# single-line json split

Tags: json, python-3.x, apache-spark, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a json file which is complicated and I am trying to split it to multiple files. Is there an approach to achieve this

My input file

```
{"Ename":"xyz LLC","entity_type":"Third Party","version":"1.0.0","in_network":[{"neg_arr":"ffs","name":"PULMONARY EDEMA & RESPIRATORY FAILURE","billing_type":"MS-DRG","billing_version":"2022","billing_code":"189","description":"PULMONARY EDEMA & RESPIRATORY FAILURE","negotiated_rates":[{"negotiated_prices":[{"negotiated_type":"negotiated","negotiated_rate":14678.75,"expiration_date":"9999-12-31","service_code":["21"],"billing_class":"institutional"}],"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1538244918],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"610444707"}}]}]},{"neg_arr":"ffs","name":"STERILE SUPPLY","billing_type":"RC","billing_version":"2022","billing_code":"272","description":"MEDICAL/SURGICAL SUPPLIES AND DEVICES - STERILE SUPPLY","negotiated_rates":[{"negotiated_prices":[{"negotiated_type":"negotiated","negotiated_rate":9.03,"expiration_date":"9999-12-31","service_code":["23"],"billing_class":"institutional"}],"provider_groups":[{"npi":[1902862824],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"610510934"}}]}]}}
```

Expected output file1.json

```
"Ename":"xyz LLC",
"entity_type":"Third Party",
"version":"1.0.0",
"in_network":[{"neg_arr":"ffs","name":"PULMONARY RESPIRATORY FAILURE","billing_type":"MS-DRG","billing_version":"2022","billing_code":"189","description":"PULMONARY EDEMA & RESPIRATORY FAILURE","negotiated_rates":[{"negotiated_prices":[{"negotiated_type":"negotiated","negotiated_rate":18.75,"expiration_date":"9999-12-31","service_code":["21"],"billing_class":"institutional"}],"provider_groups":[{"npi":[211],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"322"}}]}]}
```

Expected output file2.json

```
"Ename":"xyz LLC",
"entity_type":"Third Party",
"version":"1.0.0",
"in_network":[{"neg_arr":"ffs","name":"STERILE SUPPLY","billing_type":"RC","billing_version":"2022","billing_code":"272","description":"MEDICAL - STERILE SUPPLY","negotiated_rates":[{:[{"negotiated_type":"negotiated","negotiated_rate":9.03,"expiration_date":"9999-12-31","service_code":["23"],"billing_class":"institutional"}],"provider_groups":[{"npi":[18824],"tin":{"type":"ein","value":"6934"}}]}]}]
```

Comment: Did you check the logs (both cluster and driver)? What's going on Spark UI?

Comment: yeah they show no errors

Comment: And refreshing the notebook page (by reloading it) helps to render the output value?

Comment: tried that as well,my external table has set of json files in gz folder can that be a reason ? @AlexanderVolok